# Minimize the number of consecutive equal extractions in a deque of map<string, string>

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, deque, maximize

I hope this place is the best for this kind of question.

I've the following problem (I think is more complex than it appears).

I'm using a double-ended queue (deque) data structure of strings.
deque < string > extractions;

The deque contains only N different strings, every string repeated for M times in random order, so that the lenght of the deque is N*M, for example, suppose M=4, N=2, string1="A", string2="B":

```
extractions[1] = "A"
extractions[2] = "A"
extractions[3] = "B"
extractions[4] = "B"
extractions[5] = "A"
extractions[6] = "B"
extractions[7] = "B"
extractions[8] = "A"
```

I'm in search of an algorithm which allows me to find an interesting configuration in which there aren't two consecutive equal elements, in this case there should be only two solutions, the "A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B" and the "B","A","B","A","B","A","B","A".
For "interesting" configuration I mean the configuration not simply given by a number N of nested loops.

A very stupid solution I've implemented is to randomly shuffle the deck with `std::random_shuffle` until no occurence of consecutive equal elements is found, but this is both stupid and slow, this is more like a bogosort...

Clearly maximizing the edit distance between the strings should be better.
Some hint?

Comment: It's easy to produce a configuration that has no consecutive identical elements. Are you looking for a particular one (e.g. the one that's the closest to your starting configuration, or something along those lines)?

Comment: No i'm not interested in a particular configuration, the only thing is that consecutive extractions should be avoided.
Clearly this example sucks but for N=3 we can have more interesting examples,
a possibile allowed configuration for N=3 M=3 should be
A,B,C,B,A,C,A,B,C

and not only the straightforward configuration:
A,B,C,A,B,C,A,B,C

this kind of configurations are basically the ones I'm starting from, so they aren't interesting.

Comment: Then you need to clarify your question, stating that you're looking for "interesting" configurations, and defining the exact meaning of "interesting".

Comment: Your proposed solution is hauntingly similar to [bogosort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with a trivial configuration, e.g for N=4 an M=4, start from

A B C D A B C D A B C D A B C D

and then run a standard shuffling algorithm but observing the constraint that you do not bring two equal elements next to each others, i.e.

```
for i = 0 .. N*M - 2
  let j = random(N*M - 2 - i) + i + 1
    if ((i == 0 || array[i - 1] != array[j])
        && (array[i + 1] != array[j])
        && (array[i] != array[j - 1])
        && (j == N*M - 1 || array[i] != array[j + 1]))
      swap (array[i], array[j])
```

This should leave you very quickly with a random configuration that fulfills your requirement of not having two consecutive equal elements.

Comment: what should the random( n ) functions returns? A random number in the range [0,n) ? or in range [1,n] ?

Comment: Yes, this definitely works, but it has to be applied until there are no consecutives.

I would enclose it with a 

    while ( sumConsecutiveElements(array) != 0 ) 
        yourFunction(array)

where sumConsecutiveElements(array) is a function which returns the number of consecutive equal elements.

Thanks for your great answer!

Comment: It doesn't need to be applied until there are no consecutives, because the algorithm ensures that there aren't any during any moment during the algorithm's execution...

Answer (score 0):

```
int total = m * n;

for (int i = 1; i < total - 1; i++)
  {
    int j = total - 1;
    while ((j > i) && (queue[i - 1] == queue[j]))
      j--;
    if (queue[i - 1] == queue[j])
      {
        String aux = queue[i - 1];
        queue[i - 1] = queue[j];
        queue[j] = aux;
      }
  }
```

This code is not tested, but you get the idea.

Comment: at a first implementation this solution doesn't work, then the aux string is unuseful, a simple std::swap can do the job for you. Maybe it's my implementation wrong but I tested it both with .at() and with iterators...

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with recursion:

example is in C#: I find it more "speaking" than the nested loops:

```
public List<String> GetPermutations(string s, IEnumerable<String> parts, string lastPart, int targetLength)
{
    List<String> possibilities = new List<string>();

    if (s.Length >= targetLength)
    {
        possibilities.Add(s);
        return possibilities;
    }

    foreach (String part in parts)
    {
        if (!part.Equals(lastPart))
        {
            possibilities.AddRange(
               GetPermutations(s + part, parts, part, targetLength));
        }
    }

    return possibilities;
}
```

usage:

```
List<String> parts = new List<String>() { "A", "B", "C"};
int numOccurences = 4;

List<String> results = 
    GetPermutations("", parts, "", numOccurences * parts.Count );
```

**But if you want just a single possible solution (which is way faster to calculate of course):**

it will create you a random, non trivial solution like: CACBCBCABABACAB (for A, B, C)

```
public String GetRandomValidPermutation(
     string s, 
     List<String> parts, 
     string lastPart, 
     int targetLength)
{
    if (s.Length >= targetLength)
    {
        return s;
    }

    String next = String.Empty; 
    while(
      (next = parts[new Random().Next(0, parts.Count)])
      .Equals(lastPart)
    ){}

    return GetRandomValidPermutation(s + next, parts, next, targetLength);
}
```

call:

```
String validString = 
    GetRandomValidPermutation("", parts, "", numOccurences * parts.Count);
```

Comment: yes but this doesn't help me to unshuffle the list, only to produce a trivial configuration A,B,C,A,B,C,A,B,C...Am I wrong?

Comment: it returns a complete list of valid combinations. Starting from ABA... ending with ZYZ... (in case of whole alphabet).